# How to save objects from a list in XML file?

Tags: c#, xml

sorry for the question, but I need help. I have a program, on which you can create cars and people. You can edit or remove the cars/people or do other things.

Now I want so save the cars and people in a XML file. But I never worked with XML before, I'm a beginner.

So I want to start with the cars. I have a list with cars and with "producer, colour, license plate, ..."

so here is what I have:

```
    public static void SaveFileAuto(List<Car> cars)
    {
        Car car = new Car();

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        FileStream str = new FileStream(@"car.xml", FileMode.Create);
        ser.Serialize(str, cars);
    }
```

So, I have no idea, what to do next or what is missing or wrong.

Comment: You are creating a new car `Car car = new Car();`  So when you call Car later, it is a different instance of the car than what you passed in.  You will want to loop through your list passed into the method to save each one.

Comment: @JoshAdams okay so I don't have to create a new car? and try with a foreach loop?

Comment: @Ronja well your method is taking a List of Cars, so that list should already have a collection of car objects that have all their properties. Then as Josh mentioned you can just do a foreach loop. foreach(var car in cars) { //do what you need with "car" in here }

Comment: @JoshAdams, no, he is creating a new Car, but he's never using it. He's using the cars passed as argument

Comment: This is equivalent to doing the "regular" for loop. for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) { cars[i]....}

Comment: @Magnetron Good catch, I thought he passed `car` not `cars` at the end.  He is actually never using `car`.  @ronja you can just loop through your list then.

Comment: Okay, thank you all, but do I need to put the Serializer in the loop? or  before?

Comment: If you serialize a list then no, you don't need to use a loop.  The serializer will do the iteration for you.

Comment: @squillman so okaay, I'm confused :D I don't need a loop?

Comment: No loop needed. But you need to close the stream ...

Comment: @Ronja Sorry to confuse you.  You would use the loop if you wanted to create the XML and save it in a particular way. I will add an answer below showing how you can accomplish the same result in two different ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, the `Car car = new Car();` line as well as the `StringWriter writer...` line are obviously obsolete.

Secondly, you want to serialize a `List<Car>`, not simply a `Car`. So you have to create the `XmlSerializer` accordingly.

Third point: wrap the usage of the stream in a `using` statement, so it is cleanly closed after usage:

```
public static void SaveFileAuto(List<Car> cars)
{
    // create serializer for typeof(List<Car>) not typeof(Car)
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Car>));

    using (FileStream str = new FileStream(@"car.xml", FileMode.Create))
        ser.Serialize(str, cars);
}
```

To load and deserialize the xml file again, you can also use the `XmlSerializer`:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Car>));

List<car> cars;
using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"car.xml", FileMode.Open))
    cars = (List<Car>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

Comment: Thank you! So it's the right way like this? To save it as a xml? or is something missing?

Comment: "So it's the right way like this?" If want to do exactly this, yes. I'd recommend to have the data in a DataSet, though. A DataSet can very easily be saved as xml. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb27k0tf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Ronja it's one possible way. What is the "right way" for you I can't tell. It depends on your special requirements not shown in your question. The `XmlSerializer` by default writes all _public properties_ into the xml, with the property's name as tag-name. You may need to customize that (via attributes) or you may even want to serialize _fields_ as well. In that case, different approaches depending on your requirements may be more appropriate. Another point to consider is: _who wants to deserialize_ the xml will the information be sufficient.

Comment: @RenéVogt thank you it works!! :) so do you have any idea, what I should do if I wanted to read the xml file with every program start? Also with a Serializer?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the xml however you'd like.  You are better off using the XmlSerializer.  [Referenced From Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/19906c15-a186-4a0e-8d20-81d48a25ee06/how-to-create-xml-file-by-iterating-through-list?forum=csharpgeneral)

```
// Your Car Class
public class Car
{
    public string Producer{ get; set; }
    public string Colour{ get; set; }
    public int LicensePlate { get; set; }
    public int CarID { get; set; }
}

// The List<Car>
var cars= new List<Car>(){ 
    new Car() { Producer= "Ford", Colour= "Red", LicensePlate= 123},
    new Car() { Producer= "Chevy", Colour= "Green", LicensePlate= 333}       
    };

// Build the document
public static void SaveFileAuto(List<Car> cars)
{
  XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        // This is the root of the document
        new XElement("Cars", 
        from car in cars
        select
            new XElement("Car", new XAttribute("ID", car.CarID),
            new XElement("Producer",car.Producer),
            new XElement("Colour", car.Colour),
            new XElement("LicensePlate", car.LicensePlate));

   // Write the document to the file system            
   xdoc.Save("C:/Working Directory/Cars.xml");
}
```